# get data back from ajax php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hello i am trying to add live search functionality to my website i used ajax php to do so

i would like when i click on a live search result to change the value of the live search field and to put the id of the selected result in a hidden form field to be used in insert later

i tried doing it in the code below but it gives the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        load_data();
        function load_data(query)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"search.php",
                method:"GET",
                data:{textbook:query},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            var search = $(this).val();
            if(search != '')
            {
                load_data(search);
            }
            else
            {
                load_data();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>

    selectxt(id, textbood_adress){

        $('#search').val(textbood_adress);

    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group input-group" id="textbook">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"  class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
</span>

</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and for the php

```
include ("../../includes/config.php");
$output = '';

if(isset($_GET['textbook'])){

    $key=$_GET['textbook'];
$key = $db->escape($key);



    $results = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * from textbook where textbook_address like '%{$key}%' ");

    if($db->count > 0){

        $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table bordered">
       <tr>
         <th>Textbook address</th>
         <th>select?</th>
        </tr>';

        foreach ($results as $result) {

            $output .= '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$result["textbook_address"].'</td>
    <td><a id="selectclick" href="#" onclick="selectxt('.$result['id'].','.$result['textbook_address'].')">select</a></td>
   </tr>
  ';


        }

        echo $output;

    }else{

        echo "<span>No results for your search</span>";

    }






}



?>
```

Comment: Use *prepared statements*. Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: As for the ajax, I suggest you to use [typeahead js and bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). Implementing an ajax search on keyup will very quickly deplete your resources.

Comment: @Cemal yes i will do securing the code later i am just doing the structure right now

Comment: It's crucial not only for security but for implementation as well. What if I were to search for the text "**I'm ready**" .Your code will  fail to run properly because the sql query will be wrong.

Comment: @Cemal i would like when i click on a live search result to change the value of the live search field and to put the id of the selected result in a hidden form field to be used in insert later

Comment: @Cemal i tried doing it many times it always gives error so i need help not writing code for me

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Cemal i am trying to call the function selectxt(id, textbookaddress) from the main script through clicking on the live search result but it gives this error in console Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function declaration is wrong. Change your javascript code 
from

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            method:"GET",
            data:{textbook:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script>

selectxt(id, textbood_adress){

    $('#search').val(textbood_adress);

}
</script>
```

to

```
<script>

function load_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {textbook: query},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function selectxt(id, textbood_adress) {
    $('#search').val(textbood_adress);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    load_data();
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        var search = $(this).val();
        if (search != '') {
           load_data(search);
        }
        else {
           load_data();
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Your javascript function declaration were wrong and also misplaced. Here's an example [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xaeVoB).

> Please check and make sure that `$result['textbook_address']` doesn't have **'** in it. This will break your html output as the browser will try to interpret it wrong

Comment: it gives the same error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: i would like to call the function selecttxt when the person click on live search result

Comment: i know that the remaining code is right the issue with calling selecttext on the right way also i added $db->escape($key) which take care of code escaping and secuirty in my database class

Comment: no actually i can't call it right way i have to declare it right and call it right

Comment: If the code fixed your problem `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )`, Please accept this as it solved your problem. If you have another error, please ask a new question.

Comment: Have you checked the codepen? There's no error with what you have supplied. If there's another error, then it's not from what I have supplied you.

Comment: when i test if the function is called or not by adding alert("function called") in it no alerts appear this means that it is not called at all so i think the error from calling it or passing parameters to it

Comment: As I have previously said, this answer solves the problem of `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )`. For that you need to ask another question.

Comment: no the error is still there i can provide a screenshot

Comment: PLease do that. Also supply the whole html of the actual page.

Comment: the whole html [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxJemM)

screenshot [link](https://prnt.sc/kxfn2p)

Comment: i think the error from passing string to the function in php script

Comment: Don't put your php page in codepen. Just open your page and press ctrl+u (or view source) and copy all that html that is **in the browser** to a place like anotepad.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180582/discussion-between-cemal-and-marcos-t-gobriel).